# How to rewrite all urls with .net in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, url, sitefinity

I have a Sitefinity project, version 10.2. I need to set the default url. What I mean is currently the project looks like this: url/Sitefinity. I need everything in the website to be like this: url/Portal/Sitefinity. I'm somewhat new to .Net and I don't know how to handle this. I've tried so far to add a rewrite in web.config, but it generates an error.

```
<rule name="Portal prefix">
   <match url="Portal/(.*)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to change the backend URL - it is hardcoded in many places in code, so better leave it.

From [this article](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-change-the-path-to-the-backend):

"***The path to the backend is hard-coded and cannot be changed.
You can add some rewrite rules in IIS to forward URLs pointing to an alternate path to /Sitefinity, but the /Sitefinity path will still be available.***"